# Elasticsearch: why can't find by `term` query but can find by `match` query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `Elasticsearch 11` for query text.

I have below query but it doesn't return any document.

```
POST/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term":{
      "metric_name" : {"value": "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits","boost": 1.0}
    }
  }
}
```

Then I change it to `text` query like below which can find the matched document:

```
POST/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match":{
      "metric_name" : "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits"
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the doc in `term` query, it matches exact term but the value `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits` is an exact one for `metric_name`, so why `term` query doesn't return anything?

Comment: Can you share the mapping type of `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits`? My guess is that this field is of type `text`, hence analyzed by the standard analyzed and indexed as `consumedreadcapacityunits` token (i.e. all lowercase).

Comment: yes, you are right, it is `text` type for this field. How can I change it in order to support term query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match query analyzes the search term, based on the standard analyzer (if no analyzer is specified) and then matches the analyzed term with the terms stored in the inverted index. By default `text` type field uses a standard analyzer if no analyzer is specified. For eg. SchooL gets analyzed to school

Term query returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field. If you have not defined any explicit index mapping, then you need to add .keyword to the field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer.

As mentioned in the comments above mapping type of `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits` is `text`, so you can perform term query on `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits` by updating your index mapping

If you want to store the `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits` field as of both text and keyword type, then you can [update your index mapping as shown below to use multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex)

```
PUT /_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then reindex the data again. After this, you will be able to perform term query using the "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits.keyword" field as of keyword type and "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits" as of text type

OR the other way is to create a new index, with the below index mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then index the data in this new index